# Queue implementation using linked list

Tags: c#, unit-testing, linked-list, queue

I have implemented a queue data structure using linked list in C#. I have also associated my implementation with unit tests. Is this implementation correct? Any suggestion?

```
namespace QueueDataStructure
{
    internal class Node
    {
        internal int value;
        internal Node next;
    }

    public class Queue
    {
        private Node head;
        private int size;

        public Queue(){}

        public void Enqueue(int n)
        {
            if(head == null) // queue is empty
            {
                head = new Node{
                    value = n,
                    next = null
                };
            }
            else // queue has items
            {
                var oldHead = head;
                head = new Node
                {
                    value = n,
                    next = oldHead
                };
            }
            size++;
        }

        public int? Dequeue()
        {
            if (size == 0)
                return null;

            var node = head;
            Node previous = node;
            while (node.next != null)
            {
                previous = node;
                node = node.next;
            }
            previous.next = null;
            size--;
            return node.value;
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get { return size; }
        }

        public string PrintElements()
        {
            var node = head;
            int[] elements = new int[size];
            int i = 0;
            while (node != null)
            {
                elements[i++] = node.value;
                node = node.next;
            }
            return string.Join(" ", elements);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using QueueDataStructure;

namespace TestQueue
{
    [TestClass]
    public class Tests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestQueue()
        {
            var queue = new Queue();
            Assert.AreEqual(0, queue.Count);
            Assert.AreEqual(null, queue.Dequeue());

            queue.Enqueue(1);
            queue.Enqueue(2);
            queue.Enqueue(3);
            Assert.AreEqual(3, queue.Count);
            Assert.AreEqual("3 2 1", queue.PrintElements());

            Assert.AreEqual(1, queue.Dequeue());
            Assert.AreEqual(2, queue.Dequeue());
            Assert.AreEqual(3, queue.Dequeue());
            Assert.AreEqual(0, queue.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Good

- You are following the .NET Naming Guidelines
- The variables are in the correct scope

#### Review

Omitting braces `{}` although they might be optional can lead to hidden and therfore hard to track down bugs. I would like to encourage you to always use them.

---

Regarding `public string PrintElements()` I would suggest to simply override `ToString()` which is more idiomatic.

---

If we take a closer look at the `Enqueue(int n)` method we notice that the difference between the `if` and the `else` part is simply the value of `next`. We can remove this code duplication by adding a variable `Node node` and assign `head` like so

```
public void Enqueue(int n)
{
    Node node = head;
    head = new Node
    {
        value = n,
        next = node
    };
    
    size++;
}
```

much better, isn't it ?

---

A C# developer would expect from a `Queue` that if the `Queue` is empty (in your case if `size == 0`) a call to `Dequeue()` would throw an `InvalidOperationException`.

Answer (score 4):

There is an strong feel of [Shlemiel the painter’s algorithm](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/) in removing entries from the queue. The longer the queue, the longer it takes.  Adding a reference to the tail will prevent this.

Also, this is pretty much a textbook example of something to which we can apply generics.

```
public class Queue<T>
{
    private readonly static Node<T> HeadNode = new Node<T>(default(T));

    private readonly Node<T> _head;
    private Node<T> _tail;

    public Queue()
    {
        _head = HeadNode;
        _tail = _head;
    }

    public int Count { get; private set; }

    public void Enqueue(T value)
    {
        _tail = _tail.Add(value);
        Count++;
    }

    public T Dequeue()
    {
        Count--;
        return _head.Remove();          
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join(" ", GetValues().Select(v => v.ToString()));
    }

    private IEnumerable<T> GetValues()
    {
        var current = _head.Next;
        while(current != null)
        {
           yield return current.Value;
           current = current.Next;
        }
    }

    # region Node

    private class Node<TNode>
    {
        public Node(T value)
        {
           Value = value;
        }
        public T Value { get;  }
        public Node<T> Next { get; private set; }

        public Node<T> Add(T value)
        {
           Next = new Node<T>(value);
           return Next;
        }

        public T Remove()
        {
           if(Next == null)
           {
              throw new InvalidOperationException();
           }
           var ret = Next.Value;
           Next = Next.Next;
           return ret;
        }
    }

    #endregion 
}
```

- There is no need for the `Node` class to be visible outside the `Queue`. It is an implementation detail of the `Queue`.
- Adding the permanent `_head` removes any need for null checks
- `size` and `Count` can be merged.
- Moving the `Add()` and `Remove()` operations into the `Node` defines the interface for the `Node` in terms of operations one can perform on it, rather than in terms of the visible members. We can't erroneously scribble on either the `Value` or the `Next` reference.

Comment: the "permanent `_head`" is often called "sentinel"

Answer (score 2):

In addition to excellent answers above, I'd add *interface implementation* - a typical .NET/C# generic data structure, such as the `System.Collections.Generic.Queue<T>` class, can be passed in to functions or stored in other data containers as an `IEnumerable<T>`. Here's an example implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` (you'd need to make your queue generic):

```
public class Queue<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    //...
    //Your code
    //...

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new QueueEnumerator(this);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    //Inner class
    private class QueueEnumerator : IEnumerator<T>
    {
        private Queue<T> queue;
        private Node<T> currentNode;

        public QueueEnumerator(Queue<T> queue)
        {
            this.queue = queue;
        }

        public T Current => currentNode.value;

        object IEnumerator.Current => Current;

        public void Dispose() { }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            if(queue.head == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if(currentNode == null)
            {
                currentNode = queue.head;
                return true;
            }

            if(currentNode.next == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            currentNode = currentNode.next;
            return true;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            currentNode = null;
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: Since your `Enqueue` method inserts *before head*, you'd need to modify the enumeration accordingly, or change `Enqueue` method to insert *after head*, or make you backing linked list a doubly-linked list (so you can traverse it backwards from tail to head).